# Using $wpdb->prepare query for IN clauses

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

// get_fav_fruit returns the fruit name as a string

```
$multipleFavFruits = get_fav_fruit( );

$color = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(“SELECT color FROM $fruitsTable WHERE fruit IN (%s) , $multipleFavFruits));
```

the above solution does not works for me.

I have created right solution for it please have a look in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Count the number of fruit names
$favFruitsCount = count($multipleFavFruits);

// Prepare the right amount of placeholders, in an array
// For strings, you would use, '%s'
$stringPlaceholders = array_fill(0, $favFruitsCount, '%s');

// Put all the placeholders in one string '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,...'
$placeholdersForFavFruits = implode(', ', $stringPlaceholders);

// Now, our query with multiple placeholders would be:
$query = "SELECT color FROM $fruitsTable WHERE fruit IN ($placeholdersForFavFruits)";

// Get the corresponding colors for the fruits
$multipleColors = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query, $multipleFavFruits));
```

Comment: There should be `()` around `$placeholdersForFavFruits`. And quotes should be usual, not magic.